# Scientific notation in chart director

Tags: .net, vb.net, charts, scientific-notation, chart-director

Good morning, guys!
I need a little some help with Chart Director in VB.net.
I need to know, how to show the scale Y in scientific notation.
I need to show the scale Y like "1.6E-05" And not "0.000016".

My chart is showing like this "0.000018, 0.000019". I need to show like "1.6E-05".
[How my chart is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlpZY.png)

Comment: [Parameter Substitution and Formatting](https://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdnet.htm#paramsub.htm) and search for `scientific notation`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 c.yAxis().setLabelFormat("{value|E1}")
```